# How to set CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin on Wasabi

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, cloud, cyberduck, wasabi

I need a fairly simple method to make a bucket in Wasabi (uses much of AWS S3 api) have the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

I do not want to install the AWS A3 API and am using CyberDuck and S3 Browser for Windows.  S3 Browser has a CORS configuration option and I have attempted to submit an valid XML rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/" />
 <CORSRule>
   <Access-Control-Allow-Origin>*</Access-Control-Allow-Origin>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

... but I receive an error:

[image]

[I] NotImplemented: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented TaskID: 432

Any thoughts or suggestions?